# Звуковий слівний набір

Tags: фонетика, resource-request

> Words in SMALL CAPS are the standard *lexical sets*. Words in the lexical sets BATH and CLOTH may be given two transcriptions, the former either with /ɑː/ or /æ/, the latter with /ɒ/ or /ɔː/.

При перегляді [МФА Анґлської](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/English) мови натрапив на тямку [слівний набір](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_set) — перелік слів, котрі відповідають за якусь особливу рису зі звуцтва. Можливо, для сучасної Української наукова тямка має гиншу назву, буду радий, якшчо вкажуть.

Зьвісно, маємо таблицю для сучасного українського письменства виду [такої](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F_%D0%9C%D0%A4%D0%90_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8), але мені цїкаво для серединної Української, аби можна було враховувати і говірки, як [тут](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects) для Анґлських говірок.

Comment: А чим саме [це](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Таблиця_МФА_для_української_мови) не підходить: (а) хочете щось типу такого, але для певних діалектів, а не для мови загалом; (б) хочете щось типу такого, але щоб було стандартизоване, а не просто навмання вибране; (в) обидві здогадки неправильні?

Comment: @Sasha Ваша ланка вже була в мойому запиті. Радше **(б)**. Чому не **(а)** — коли дивити лише для певної говірки, то там можливо нерозкритий звук, властивий гиншим, а отже відняти одного слова з слівного набору. Хочу шчось штибу унормованого, але на рівні говірок Українських мов. Ось [тут](https://i.tyzhden.ua/content/photoalbum/2012/10_12/04/tyshenko/tyshenko.pdf) наприклад дуже лиш частково розкрито на рівнї Словянської родини. Хоча я не проти брати і МФА для говірок, то може полегшити справу.

Comment: Дякую. («Ваша ланка вже була в мойому запиті» — я знаю, я коментував лише тому, що хотів зрозуміти, чим не підійшло.)

Comment: Очевидно, що подібних стандартизованих наборів не існує нині в природі, бо майже ніхто не займається порівнянням різних українських діялектів, обмежуючись вивченням якогось окремого чи невеликої групи. Та й для діялектів майже немає описів засобами МФА; наприклад, я колись намагався скласти щось подібне, однак не знайшов необхідної інформації.